# What are these errors in BlackBerry 10 Mometics while trying to build LAME?

Tags: blackberry-10, lame

I'm trying to build with the LAME files but I'm getting these errors on the machine.h file

What's going on?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer :** your defines are not what they are supposed to be. The BB10 SDK provides `stdlib.h` and `string.h` so you should either :

- add a `#define STDC_HEADERS 1` somewhere in the include path (inside `version.h` maybe, because it's seems to be included by everyone else)
- add `DEFINES += STDC_HEADERS` to your .pro file.

---

You are trying to build your library inside Momentics.

That's usually the fastest way to go.

The issue is that you are skipping the whole `configure` part of Lame compilation, which was supposed to gather insight about the system you're trying to compile on by trial and error.

I haven't looked at Lame specificaly, but usually `configure` either creates an header file with all the right defines or add them in the `Makefile` it creates as arguments to the compiler.

Momentics, on the other way, compiles all .c|.cpp file and link them all together using `qmake` to handle all Qt specific bits. Momentics sets the right environment, and then there is a lot of scripts to handle all the BB10 processes (package, sign, ..).

So you'll have to provide the missing parts. Usually it's faster to create a new `config.h` from scratch, but sometimes you may want to use a console with the BB10 SDK environment and do a `./configure` manually. Don't forget that the simulator is x86 and the real thing is ARM, so you will have take care of that too (Endianness/optimization issues).

Comment: Thanks. I got it to compile by commenting out the four errored lines starting with #ifndef... I actually got LAME to work but it is giving me a strange output where the audio is a very deep pitch. My code for encoding looks good and it makes me wonder it my LAME build has problems possibly for the reasons you mention above. As a programmer I'm somewhere between novice and medium-low...makefiles, defines, configuring are something I'm almost totally ignorant about...so I have to learn.

Comment: I added DEFINES += STDC_HEADERS in the pro file and removed the commenting out those lines. It built fine. Thanks. Still my MP3's have a low deep pitch. Must research more. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: As an update to this: The low-pitch rate was due to me not matching sample rates in my code. Thanks again for the help.